# Zend_Http_Client and TLS 1.2 in Zend Framework 1

Tags: zend-framework, tls1.2

I can see here how to set the socket adapter for Zend_Http_Client

http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.http.client.adapters.html

The examples they give are tls or sslv2.

Does anyone know what the setting is for tls1.2?

I've tried a few but I'm just guessing. I get errors along the lines of:

```
Unable to find the socket transport "tls1.2" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP?'
```

If I try tls on it's own I get:

```
Unable to Connect to tls://www.sandbox.paypal.com:443
```

(For others Googling this is to fix our IPN verification with PayPal which gives the following error on our SSL connection:

```
Error in cURL request: error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure
```

)

Answer (score 4):

You were close! Set `ssltransport` to `tlsv1.2`.

```
$config = array(
    'adapter'      => 'Zend_Http_Client_Adapter_Socket',
    'ssltransport' => 'tlsv1.2'
);

$client = new Zend_Http_Client('https://www.sandbox.paypal.com', $config);

$response = $client->request();
echo $response->getStatus();
```

Figured it out by first checking what `Zend_Http_Client_Adapter_Socket` uses to send HTTP requests, which turned out to be `stream_socket_client()`. You can run the [`stream_get_transports()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-get-transports.php) on your system to view the list of available socket transports.

See [SSL/TLS version selection](http://php.net/manual/en/migration56.openssl.php#migration56.openssl.crypto-method) in the *OpenSSL changes in PHP 5.6.x* migration guide for more examples of how to select specific SSL/TLS versions.

Tested with PHP 5.6 on Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty, which supports TLSv1.2 out of the box.